# nested dictionary on python?

Tags: python, dictionary, text, nested-lists

I have a text file with names, ages and gender.

```
John, 55, Male
Toney, 23, Male
Karin, 42, Female
Cathie, 29, Female
Rosalba, 12, Female
Nina, 50, Female
Burton, 16, Male
Joey, 90, Male
```

Now I want to do a def read_person_data(persons): that can return the information as a nested dictionary. For example the key ’John’ has
the dictionary {’Age’: 55, ’Gender’: ’Male’} as value. The keys in the main
dictionary should be the name without the comma though, so do I have to do strip or?

I have attemped with this code:

```
with open('persons.txt','r') as infile:
    dic=[]
    for line in infile:
        s=line.split()
        dic.append(s[0])
    dictofnames={i : s[1] for i in dic}       
    
print(dictofnames)
```

By making a list first and then turning it into a dictionary, but I get wrong age on every name, and don't understand how to also then add ,gender: 'male' after the name and the age?? it has to be a dictionary though, and not a list with the format {’Age’: 55, ’Gender’: ’Male’} on the key for a specific name. Also when i do a def function it doesnt append onto the dictionary, how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to the following.

```
    import re
    with open('persons.txt','r') as infile:
        dic={}
        for line in infile:
            s=re.split(', |\n',line)
            dic[s[0]] = {}
            dic[s[0]]['Age'] = s[1]
            dic[s[0]]['Gender'] = s[2]       
    print(dic)
```

**Output:**
{'John': {'Age': '55', 'Gender': 'Male'}, 'Toney': {'Age': '23', 'Gender': 'Male'}, 'Karin': {'Age': '42', 'Gender': 'Female'}, 'Cathie': {'Age': '29', 'Gender': 'Female'}, 'Rosalba': {'Age': '12', 'Gender': 'Female'}, 'Nina': {'Age': '50', 'Gender': 'Female'}, 'Burton': {'Age': '16', 'Gender': 'Male'}, 'Joey': {'Age': '90', 'Gender': 'Male'}}

Answer (score 0):

You want to take advantage of `pandas`, and use Dataframe to dictionary conversion as shown here:

```
import pandas as pd
def read_person_data(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep=',',header=None,names=['Name','Age','Gender'])
    df.set_index('Name').T.to_dict()
    return df

read_person_data('persons.txt')
```

Output:

```
{'Burton': {'Age': 16, 'Gender': ' Male'},
 'Cathie': {'Age': 29, 'Gender': ' Female'},
 'Joey': {'Age': 90, 'Gender': ' Male'},
 'John': {'Age': 55, 'Gender': ' Male'},
 'Karin': {'Age': 42, 'Gender': ' Female'},
 'Nina': {'Age': 50, 'Gender': ' Female'},
 'Rosalba': {'Age': 12, 'Gender': ' Female'},
 'Toney': {'Age': 23, 'Gender': ' Male'}}
```

As shown by @Arvind Kumar you could do the following as well:

```
def read_person_data(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as lines:
        dictofnames=dict()
        for line in lines:
            l=line.split(",")
            dictofnames[l[0]]={'Age':l[1],'Gender':l[2].strip()}       
    return dictofnames
```

Comment: Does that not serve your purpose @puhhyahh?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you achieve want you want:

```
with open('persons.txt','r') as infile:
    data=dict()

    for line in infile:
        s=line.split(",")
        data[s[0]]={'Age':s[1],'Gender':s[2].strip()}       

print(data)
```

which results to:

```
{'John': {'Age': ' 55', 'Gender': 'Male'},
'Toney': {'Age': ' 23', 'Gender': 'Male'},
'Karin': {'Age': ' 42', 'Gender': 'Female'},
'Cathie': {'Age': ' 29', 'Gender': 'Female'},
'Rosalba': {'Age': ' 12', 'Gender': 'Female'},
'Nina': {'Age': ' 50', 'Gender': 'Female'},
'Burton': {'Age': ' 16', 'Gender': 'Male'},
'Joey': {'Age': ' 90', 'Gender': 'Male'}}
```